# How to replace brackets without losing the brackets using sed command?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed, console

I'm trying to search into the files the word: `"http://{$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]}"`

and if I find some line with that item I want to add `/suitecrm/` next to the closing curly brace "}"

or replace it with: `'http://{$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]}/suitecrm'` , but I need to escape the brackets without losing them,

How can I do that? please!!!

this is my code:

```
sudo grep -lir "HTTP_HOST" /var/www/html/suitecrm/ | xargs sudo sed -i 's,http://{$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]},http://{$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]}/suitecrm,g’ ;
```

Comment: You should probably start by fixing your quotes. There's some ***”*** in there. I'm surprised it did not cause a Bash error.

Comment: yeah well, that is my minor issue... thanks!

Comment: Why did you remove the formatting we applied to the question?

Comment: sorry! I'm a little bit new here... >.<

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sed -i 's,http://{\$_SERVER\["HTTP_HOST"\]},http://{\$_SERVER\["HTTP_HOST"\]}/suitecrm,g’
```

Eg:

```
$ echo 'http://{$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]}' | sed 's,http://{\$_SERVER\["HTTP_HOST"\]},http://{\$_SERVER\["HTTP_HOST"\]}/suitecrm,'
http://{$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]}/suitecrm
```

Actually I just batch replaced `$` to `\$`, `[` to `\[`, and `]` to `\]`.
It's called `Escaping`, certain characters have special meanings in RE, when you refer to them literally, you have to `Escape` them.

Check this:
[Escapes](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Escapes.html)